# Kotlin Data Classes support in Protobuf

Tags: kotlin, protocol-buffers, data-class, protobuf-java

I am implementing protobuf recently in our kotlin project. 
I am receiving the binary data and deserialising it to Proto object using the proto file.

But I would like have that converted to data class. 
I could not find any supporting information about how to do this.

Is it possible to get data class from binary data or from deserialized proto object??

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use [pb-and-k](https://github.com/cretz/pb-and-k) which has the kotlin code generator and will generate data classes for you based off of the `.proto` files

Answer (score 0):

If you have know the structure of the data and can write your data classes upfront, you might want to have a look at [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization). It is an official Kotlin project and supports protobuf out-of-the-box.